# Adding +1 to a Firebase database, keeps running until it is at maximum capacity - how to get it to only add one on run?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wanting to make a function that just adds +1 onto the existing database value - it is numeric so resevered + 1

Here is me trialing it inside a function, then just running it from console.

```
function AddaMember() {
  playersRef.on("value", function(data, prevChildKey) {
    var newPlayer = data.val();
    var members = firebase.database().ref("locations/hello");
    var age = newPlayer.resevered;
    const newmember = age + 1;
    console.log(age);
    members.update({
      "resevered" : newmember,
    })
  });
}
```

I just want it to add one and then stop, rather it runs until the document is full, what is the work around for this? Should I be using a loop?

Thanks, Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is using `on()` to set up a persistent listener the location of `playersRef`.  That listener will receive a callback every time *anything* changes at or under the location.  Since your listener is also writing back to a child at that location, it ends up triggering the callback again.

If you don't want a persistent listener, and instead just want to [query a single time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once), use `once()` instead of `on()`.

```
playersRef.once("value").then(snapshot => {
    // work with the data here
})
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks man - cannot upvote since don't have enough rep

Comment: You should be able to upvote and accept answers on your own questions.  You might just have to wait a while to do so.